# How to use a submit button linked to a drop down list?

Tags: javascript, html

I got a dropdown select option and I wanted to be able to select one and click on the submit button and lead me to another page (NewYork.html,Toronto.html,NewJersey.html)

```
<form action="action_page.php">
    <select>
        <option value = "0">Select your Destination..</option>
        <option value="1">New York</option>
        <option value="2">Toronto</option>
        <option value="3">New Jersey</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="myButton">
</form>
```

Comment: Should the form be submitted to `"action_page.php"`? Or only redirected to an `.html` document?

Comment: redirected to an.html document

Comment: You can remove `action="action_page.php"` from `form` element, use `submit` event, `event.preventDefault()`, set values of `option` elements to the `.html` document which user should be re-directed to, set `location.href` to `select` element `.value`

Answer (score 1):

In your actionPage you have to redirect the user to the other page.

But you have also to check security and not redirect to something you don't know.
So you can use an associative array with your form values like `$array = [1 => "newYork", 2 => "toronto"...]` and then proceed to the redirection without forgetting to exit :

```
$redirect = $array[$_POST['value']] + ".html";
header("Location: /$redirect");
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your PHP code by using `header()` and use the value from the submitted form.

```
header('Location: /'.$submittedValue.'.html');
```

Obviously you'll need to check your form input first as you'll only get a numerical value from the drop down at the moment, but you can match that to a string to use in the header function.

Please note that the head function must be higher up the page than any `echo`, `print_r()` or any other functions that will output to the browser

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `value` of `option` elements to `URL` of `.html` documents which user will be re-directed to; use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent `form` submission at `submit` event; if `select` `.value` is not `"0"`, set `location.href` to `select` `.value`

html

```
<form>
    <select>
        <option value="0">Select your Destination..</option>
        <option value="NewYork.html">New York</option>
        <option value="Toronto.html">Toronto</option>
        <option value="NewJersey.html">New Jersey</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="myButton">
</form>
```

javascript

```
document.querySelector("form")
.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent default action
  var select = this.querySelector("select");
  if (select.value !== "0") {
    location.href = select.value;
  }
})
```